Im getting 2different voltage reading coming out of my meter to the main 120v /103 could this be the reason lights are flickering every so often,?
My lights keep flickering and only getting 70v in room with three outlets . I checked the voltage in the panel n at the meter coming to can and I'm reading 100v and 120v on othe. Is this an open Neutral or?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Voltage should be close to equal between the hots and neutral.  If not equal on the main wires, first have power company come out to check.  If a lost neutral, then low volts on one side will have high volts on the other.

Do a test. Turn off all your 240V (2-pole handle-tied) breakers.  These will be dryer, range, water heater and A/C.  Do the weak circuits die completely?
